# How to show Array inside array API data on Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to show the data of this API https://swapi.dev/api/people/

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker", 
            "height": "172", 
            "mass": "77", 
            "hair_color": "blond", 
            "skin_color": "fair", 
            "eye_color": "blue", 
            "birth_year": "19BBY", 
            "gender": "male", 
        },
 ]
}
```

but I always get this error :

How to show it like name and then when someone presses the button to character detail page that shows all detail of the API data on Angular? Thank you!

**actor.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ActorService {

  apiUrl = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  tester(){
    this.http
    .get('https://swapi.dev/api/people/')
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  getActors(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`);
  }

  getActor(name: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/${name}?per_page=10`);
  }
}
```

**actor-list.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActorService } from 'src/app/core/services/actor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actor-list',
  template: `
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="columns is-multiline" *ngIf="actors">
          <div class="column is-4" *ngFor="let actor of actors | async">
            {{ actor.results.name }}
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
              <a routerLink="/users/{{ actor.results.name }}">{{ actor.results.name }}</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ActorListComponent implements OnInit {
  actors;

  constructor(private actorService: ActorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.actors = this.actorService.getActors()
  }

}
```

**actor-single.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ActorService } from 'src/app/core/services/actor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actor-single',
  template: `
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="card" *ngIf="actor">
          <h2>{{ actor.results.name }}</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ActorSingleComponent implements OnInit {
actor
  constructor( private actorService: ActorService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const actorname = params['actorname'];
      this.actorService
      .getActor(actorname)
      .subscribe(actor => this.actor = actor)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], where it notes, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the structure of the api response. There is no field `result` in a single actor. So actor name should be

```
 <h2>{{ actor.name }}</h2>
```

and response is an object with all actors in `results` property. So you can iterate through actors like this

```
<div class="column is-4" *ngFor="let actor of (actors | async)?.results">
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your source code, you used `wrong property` for object.

It should be `*ngFor="let actor of actors.results"` and change from `actor.results.name` to `actor.name`

Demo code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jjh9mx